# Using BufferedImage in J2ME

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage

Is there a way to implement `BufferedImage` class in a `J2ME` project?. I desperately need it for HSV Image Processing...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `BufferedImage` in mobile projects. Implementing it would be a nightmare with all the dependencies to this class. Best thing is to try some other image class like `Bitmap` which is available in `J2ME`

Comment: This was what I knew and it is nothing new! :-s

Comment: But this confirms what I knew was correct.. thanks any way :-)